# Z v ??: Optimal Amount of Broodlords per strategy

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

Most end game transitions for Zerg go towards Broodlords mix.  What is the optimal amount of Broodlords for the end game?  Does it vary against each opponent race?  Also, what is the best unit to mix with it against each race [other than the corrupter for anti-air]?  For example, is infestor/corrupter/broodlords only good against Terran compared to against zerg?

The reason that I have this question is: I've heard both casters in Day[9] and Psy saying that a player has 'too' many broodlords but I am curious what that specific number is roughly against each race.  Also streaming some pros on twitch.tv I've noticed the same blanket statement

Comment: can you provide the link to one of the videos where they say they are too much? because it may just be related to their situation (eg: their opponend had just 3-4 tanks lying around and some vikings and they had 10 broodlords). and i like your question btw :)

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo I will have to spend a bit and find out what video it was specifically for Day9.  I like the question overall also (which is why I asked it ;) ) and I didn't know if there was a general statement of 'no more than 10 unless ... ' that I didn't know about. I  understand it is situational but I was seeing if there was a 'general rule of thumb' for number of Broodlords.

Comment: Pssh, can never have enough GGlords ;). Seriously though... you can't. Not unless you don't have enough minerals/gas to fun a defense for them. Your question doesn't have a set answer, its completely situational and each race is different but the basic rule of thumb is if you can't defend the broods, you made too many.

Comment: @Nick122 - That is kind of what I was expecting to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very dependent on what the opponent has and what you have. If they have a huge Tank/Thor army you can't really have too many Brood Lords, but if they also have 15 Vikings then you need to have Infestor/Corruptor support or you're in trouble. "Too many" just implies that producing the Brood Lords used too many of the player's resources and thus the army available to protect those Brood Lords isn't sufficient.

Generally, your initial wave of Brood Lords in ZvT should be about 4-8 against a Terran going Bio, but that's very adaptable depending on how the game is going- if he still doesn't have a Starport or if he's going Mech, you can be a lot more greedy. I'm unsure of exact numbers for the other matchups.